# GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, group-by

There are several posts on this same topic, and I've read through them...but try as I might, I can't apply them to my issue.  I'm sure it's something dumb I'm overlooking.

What I'm trying to do is to show patients that were in a bed at a specific date and time.  Each patient has an admit and discharge date, so I'm using those to determine if they were in a bed on that particular date & time.  If I'm listing everything out, it works great.  Now I'm trying to do a summary so it just shows 3 inpatients and 1 outpatient on a given day in this location, etc.  But I'm getting the error message in the title.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TSM950_STATION.loc_ext_id AS STATION, 
convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101) AS CENSUS_DATE,
                  TSM180_CAT.cod_dtl_ds,
                  COUNT(TPM300_PAT_VISIT.vst_ext_id)
FROM         TPM300_PAT_VISIT INNER JOIN
                  TSM040_PERSON_HDR ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.psn_int_id = TSM040_PERSON_HDR.psn_int_id INNER JOIN
                  TSM950_LOCATION_REF AS TSM950_ROOM ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.loc_lvl_4_id = TSM950_ROOM.loc_int_id INNER JOIN
                  TSM950_LOCATION_REF AS TSM950_BED ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.loc_lvl_5_id = TSM950_BED.loc_int_id  INNER JOIN
                  TSM950_LOCATION_REF AS TSM950_STATION ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.loc_lvl_3_id = TSM950_STATION.loc_int_id INNER JOIN
                  TSM180_MST_COD_DTL AS TSM180_CAT ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.pat_cat_cd = TSM180_CAT.cod_dtl_int_id
WHERE     (TSM950_STATION.loc_ext_id IN ('MS', 'OB', 'SCU', 'NURS')) AND 
        (convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),TPM300_PAT_VISIT.adm_ts,101) +' 00:00:00'))<=convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101) +' 23:58:00') AND
        (convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),TPM300_PAT_VISIT.dschrg_ts,101) +' 00:00:00'))>=convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101) +' 23:59:00')
GROUP BY        TSM950_STATION.loc_ext_id, 
                 convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101),
                  TSM180_CAT.cod_dtl_ds
```

Comment: Remove entire `getdate()` expression from group by. It is constant in Sql Servers eyes.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the following expression is a constant:

```
convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101),
```

Simply remove this from your group by, so it looks like:

```
GROUP BY TSM950_STATION.loc_ext_id, TSM180_CAT.cod_dtl_ds
```

Comment: I was hung up on thinking everything in the select besides the sum or count, etc needs to be in the group by statement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` at the same time.  By definition the records will be distinct, because all similar records are in the same group...

Also, you don't need to `GROUP BY` a constant.

This give...

```
SELECT    TSM950_STATION.loc_ext_id AS STATION,
          convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101) AS CENSUS_DATE,
          TSM180_CAT.cod_dtl_ds,
          COUNT(TPM300_PAT_VISIT.vst_ext_id)
FROM      TPM300_PAT_VISIT INNER JOIN
          TSM040_PERSON_HDR ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.psn_int_id = TSM040_PERSON_HDR.psn_int_id INNER JOIN
          TSM950_LOCATION_REF AS TSM950_ROOM ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.loc_lvl_4_id = TSM950_ROOM.loc_int_id INNER JOIN
          TSM950_LOCATION_REF AS TSM950_BED ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.loc_lvl_5_id = TSM950_BED.loc_int_id  INNER JOIN
          TSM950_LOCATION_REF AS TSM950_STATION ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.loc_lvl_3_id = TSM950_STATION.loc_int_id INNER JOIN
          TSM180_MST_COD_DTL AS TSM180_CAT ON TPM300_PAT_VISIT.pat_cat_cd = TSM180_CAT.cod_dtl_int_id
WHERE         (TSM950_STATION.loc_ext_id IN ('MS', 'OB', 'SCU', 'NURS'))
          AND (convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),TPM300_PAT_VISIT.adm_ts,101) +' 00:00:00'))<=convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101) +' 23:58:00')
          AND (convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),TPM300_PAT_VISIT.dschrg_ts,101) +' 00:00:00'))>=convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),101) +' 23:59:00')
GROUP BY  TSM950_STATION.loc_ext_id, 
          TSM180_CAT.cod_dtl_ds
```

Comment: I was hung up on thinking everything in the select besides the sum or count, etc needs to be in the group by statement.  Thanks!